# Can't get ajax post in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have been looking for an answer for my answer the entire day...I have an ajax post which sends a variable value to a php page. I think the ajax post works fine according to the success pop-up but i can't get the value on php...

Here is the sample the of ajax post:

```
var value = 150;
    /*$.post('index.php',{variable:essai});*/
    /*alert("Token:"+token);*/
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php',
        type:'POST',
        data:'data1='+value,
        success : function(data)
        {
            alert("Succès envoi de la donnée!");
        },
        error : function(resultat,statut,erreur)
        {
            alert("Erreur d'envoi de la donnée!");
        },
        complete : function(resultat,statut){

        } 


    });
```

And for the php sample:

```
<div id="right-frame">
<?php include("get.php");
if (isset($_POST['data1']))
{
$variable = $_POST['data1'];
}
?>
<p class="text">Données de la borne :</p>
<table><tr>
<th bgcolor="9fbcdc"><p class="titre">Info 1</p></th>
<th bgcolor="9fbcdc"><p class="titre">Info 2</p></th>
<th bgcolor="9fbcdc"><p class="titre">Info 3</p></th>
<th bgcolor="9fbcdc"><p class="titre">Info 4</p></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><?php echo $variable; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $variable2; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $variable3; ?></th>
<th><?php echo $variable4; ?></th>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you expecting that something should actually change on your page, cause it won't, you've just done a successful ajax call, and the HTML in your PHP is in the `data` variable from the success handler

Comment: R u not getting `print_r($_POST);` in Php?

Comment: And how to call ajax request ???

Comment: Hi, when i try with the print_r($_POST); i get an array which is empty.

Comment: Actually when i look into the network, the request status is 200 so ok and in the form data the value is the good one, 150. It looks like the issue comes from the php side...

Answer (score 0):

You're sending data as `data:'data1='+value`

Try sending it like this:

```
data: {
    'data1': value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
data:'data1='+value
```

with

```
data:{'data1':value}
```

From official documentation of jquery / ajax , it says data filed required key/value pair object.

Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain *why* they should do this?